# Exception while evaluating service stack text for iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm trying to evaluate servicestack.text in tamarin project. I've created test iOS app and added to packages ServiceStack.Client 4.0.35
However it fails with exception on this simple code:
            var t = new List { "a", "b" };
            var s = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString (t);

The exception is in LicenseUtils, JsConfig. Do I need to purchase a license in order to evaluate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [free quota](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) restrictions on ServiceStack libraries which can be unlocked with a license key. ServiceStack's Text serializers allows evaluation for up to  **20 Different Types in JSON, JSV and CSV Serializers** without a license.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @mythz. However even the simplest evaluation fails on LicenseUtils issue, do I need to define something to increase the quote?
Can I find any test example for Xamarin.iOs?

Comment: @RomanKagan Sure you can check out the [HelloMobile](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile) project, it's got examples for using PCL ServiceStack Clients and sharing code between different mobile platforms.